# How to versioning/tag testframework with REST API tests against multiple Microservices?

Tags: rest, testing, microservices, versioning, tagging

We have a lot of different Microservices and we test amongst other things the REST APIs of these different Microservices. These automated REST API tests are not included in the Microservice projects/Repos. Instead we have a testautomation project containing all different tests, like API test and end2end tests, because we want to test everything as a black box.

Now the problem is that there are infinitely combinations of different Microservice versions are possible to test against on a test environment (example: Executing the tests today against Microservice A with version 1.0 and Microservice B with version 2.0 is different to execute the same tests tomorrow against Microservice A with version 1.1 and Microservice B with version 2.1). So, we will need some kind of versioning or tagging our testautomation project or the executed tests, that we are able to identify which combinations of different Microservice versions are valid and which combinations are not valid/working, because e.g. some tests will fail.

Are there any recommendations or experiences to implement and integrate such a versioning/tagging mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

To me the actual problem already lays grounded in your actual design. You state that you maintain some micro-services based on a REST architecture, though in such an environment you don't need to version any endpoint as such to start with. Fielding himself answered how a API in a REST environment should be versioned by simply responding with: [Don't](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning).

But why is that? One of the few constraints REST has is HATEOAS (or Hate-Us as I tend to pronounce it) which stands for Hypertext-As-The-Engine-Of-Application-State. This acronym basically just describes the interaction model used in the Web, which will have no preasumption on the content to receive and will only render to the user what it received, including any URIs returned by the server. A browser will trigger a state change upon calling an endpoint targeted by a URI invoked by the user. This might be a link, an image or a form-button (or what not). The core idea here is that the client will be served  by the API or server with all the information it needs to take further actions and just present the results to the user.

While browsing the Web page of your preferred manufacturer or vendor you might notice that you'll most likely receive a HTML page containing images, links and further content. The browser itself isn't aware of the product offered on that site though it is sill able to render the result to the user as it knows how to render HTML. If you visit an other page your browser will still be able to render HTML regardless of the content that page offers. Yet if one of these pages is changing in some way your browser will still be able to render the result to you, unless the server responds with a media type that your browser isn't yet aware of, which is though very unlikely on the Web.

What most self-claimed "REST" APIs however return is some arbitrary content specific to a certain API, even though most of these use `application/json` as representation format. A tailor-made client, that has some knowledge about the API built in, is usually interacting with such an API that however is very unlikely to be able to interact with any other API out there. If something on the API level changes the likelihood of breaking that client without any additional updates of it are therefore high. This is very common to RPC like systems such as SOAP, RMI and CORBA.

Such clients often assume certain endpoints such as `/api/users/12345` to return data about a particular user in a most likely JSON representation. The payload is marshalled later on to a object of the underlying programming language probably ignoring any unknown fields and nulling out specified fields that aren't available within the response. Though the fundamental problem here is that clients assume that [certain endpoints have a certain types](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). "Smart" developers will now introduce versioning to the endpoints so that the above mentioned URI will change to `/api/v1/users/12345` for a JSON representation containing the old fields while `/api/v2/users/12345` will return the new fields. Both versions, however, still describe the same user. Having two different URIs for the same user is already a bad design per se, though usually the versioning of an endpoint does not come alone. Usually the whole API itself is versioned itself so that if you encounter a breaking change you are forced to introduce a whole new API version either copying the other unmodified resources or reusing the same models internally further just exposed under multiple URIs again.

Instead of assuming endpoints to return a certain type with a predefined representation format clients and server should negotiate about the content. HTTP here in particular supports [content type negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4) where a client informs a server about its capabilities and the server should respond in a representation format understood by the client. This could be something like `application/vnd.acmee-users+json` or `application/vcard+xml` or the like. A client understanding `application/vnd.acmee-users.v2+json` i.e. might get served by the server the new representation while older clients will still inform the server that they only understand `application/vnd.acmee-users+json` and get served by such a representation. How the server handles the change internally is not of interest to the client. It is just interested in a representation format it can handle.

Though versioning media-types is also not the preferred way of versioning changes by some architects out there as you fundamentally still describe the same thing just with a bit different syntax or a slightly different semantics. HTML i.e. still ships with `application/html` (rarely with `text/html`) but not with `application/html_5` or the like. It is designed explicitly in a way to stay backwards compatible. A server generating HTML 5 output will still be rendered on a browser that only supports HTML 4.01 or 2. Maybe not all elements will be rendered the same way as on a HTML 5 compatible browser, but the client won't stop to work unexpectedly.

Mark Nottingham, who is the co-chair in the IETF HTTP working group, stated that the underlying principle of versioning is to not break existing clients. Therefore according to him

> This implies that API versioning absolutely cannot be tied to software versioning in any way; doing so will needlessly limit (and often break) your clients, and generally upset people. ([Source](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/25/web_api_versioning_smackdown))

Nottingham even states that the [product-token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-16#section-6.3) used in `User-Agent` or `Server` headers should be taken in preference to any URI or media-type versioning to produce responses specific for certain software versions. With the sheer number of client software out there I'm not the biggest fan of that approach however, as this would require the server to have certain knowledge of the capabilities of HTTP clients and their versions used. For APIs, however, that only have a limited number of clients, probably most of them also under the same control as the API/server, this could be a viable approach though.

As you might see for yourself, in a REST architecture there is no real need to version endpoints itself as client will only handle what they are served with by the API/server. Whether a product-token approach is preferable over a media-type based one might be rather opinionated. The latter one, however, should be based on standardized media-types, registered with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). In best case the media-type itself is designed in a way that is backward compatible like HTML, which might avoid introducing new media-types for the same things over and over again.

As Phil Sturgeon mentioned in one of his [blog posts](https://blog.apisyouwonthate.com/api-versioning-has-no-right-way-f3c75457c0b7)

> If people are going to design their APIs as RPC with a RESTish facade, they should just commit to being an RPC API and build endpoint for specific clients like they’re literally already doing.
>
> Just be honest about it. Hide the false intention, RPC the lot, document as such, and maybe just use gRPC.

Comment: One main fact I forgot to mention is that the microservices partly have an impact on other microservices. and these impacts are not handable without some integration tests. also these microservices will develop by different teams and sometimes they are not talking about everything ;)

Comment: I read over your answer again and I think you misunderstood my question. All the implemented microservices are versioned as you decribed, so I know what version the different services have. Some services have an impact on other services and so they have dependencies. Only after executing the automated tests against all services I will know if there are some new problems. And if there are no problems I want to tag/versioning the tests that everybody knows that this combination of API endpoints is a valid one. So, I don't want to versioning the microservices, but the testautomation project/repo.